# Error getting deleter volume plugin for volume "pv-gogs-postgres": no deletable volume plugin matched

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pvc

Kubernetes version: v1.27.4
Cloud being used: (put bare-metal if not on a public cloud)
Installation method: kubeadm
Host OS: Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Release: 20.04
Codename: focal
CNI and version: 10-weave.conflist
CRI and version: Containerd://1.6.21

Getting the same error as given in previous issue.
`Error - “error getting deleter volume plugin for volume “pv-gogs-postgres”: no deletable volume plugin matched`” Kindly suggest which will be helpful to understand the issue.

PV YAML FILE

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
name: pv-gogs-postgres
spec:
accessModes:
- ReadWriteOnce
capacity:
storage: 20Gi
persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Delete
storageClassName: “manual”
nfs:
server: 192.168.0.60
path: /mydata

While deleting the PVC (gogs-pv-claim), getting error as given below


testuser@kmasterl:~/Gogs-postgres-pvc$ kubectl describe pv pv-gogs-postgres
Name: pv-gogs-postgres
Labels:
Annotations: pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: yes
Finalizers: [kubernetes.io/pv-protection]
StorageClass: manual
Status: Failed
Claim: dev/gogs-pv-claim
Reclaim Policy: Delete
Access Modes: RWO
VolumeMode: Filesystem
Capacity: 20Gi
Node Affinity:
Message: error getting deleter volume plugin for volume “pv-gogs-postgres”: no deletable volume plugin matched
Source:
Type: NFS (an NFS mount that lasts the lifetime of a pod)
Server: 192.168.0.60
Path: /mydata
ReadOnly: false
Events:
Type Reason Age From Message
```

PV is not working as expected. Could anyone suggest what would be the issue.

Comment: Once the PV is in this failed state, try : `kubectl delete pv pv-gogs-postgres` (the underlying disk will still exist in the cloud console after this). Adding the correct annotation to `pv-gogs-postgres` may fix the issue. This is because without this annotation, `pv-gogs-postgres` is interpreted as a statically provisioned persistent volume (PV), not a dynamically provisioned PV. I think the volume has to be dynamically provisioned in order for the "**Delete**" reclaim policy to automatically delete the volume when a user deletes the corresponding PersistentVolumeClaim.

Comment: Refer to [Migrating existing PersistentVolumes](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2021/09/13/read-write-once-pod-access-mode-alpha/#migrating-existing-persistentvolumes) : 

PersistentVolume's `spec.persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy` : `Retain`, this makes your PersistentVolume will not be deleted when we delete the corresponding PersistentVolumeClaim. (The ReadWriteOncePod access mode cannot be combined with other access modes. Make sure ReadWriteOncePod is the only access mode on the PersistentVolume when updating, otherwise the request will fail).

Comment: @ Veera Nagireddy thank you for your reply. Yes you right when I delete the PVC, it does not delete data from PV and shows status as Failed. But when I delete the PV and provision both PV and PVC again, it works. But my concern why the data from PV dose not remove automatically when the PVC is deleted. So can you suggest,

Comment: @VeeraNagireddy Under which of the following conditions the “persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy = Delete” will work to delete data automatically from PV, when associated PVC is deleted,
1. The PV should be defined with storageclass, which should be configured with provisioner to enable dynamic provisioning.
OR
2. There should be appropriate storageclass + PV + PVC and CSI plugin should be configured.

Comment: Also to your statement “I think the volume has to be dynamically provisioned in order for the "Delete" reclaim policy to automatically delete the volume when a user deletes the corresponding PersistentVolumeClaim”

Comment: I found below documents, Not sure you may suggest

Reclaim Policy
PersistentVolumes that are dynamically created by a StorageClass will have the reclaim policy specified in the reclaimPolicy field of the class, which can be either Delete or Retain. If no reclaimPolicy is specified when a StorageClass object is created, it will default to Delete.

Comment: Deleting PVs can be tricky because PVs are often bound to PVCs, which are requests for storage by a user. If a PV is deleted while still bound to a PVC, it can lead to data loss or other unexpected behaviors. Refer to K[ubernetes: The Correct Way to Delete Persistent Volumes (PV](https://saturncloud.io/blog/kubernetes-the-correct-way-to-delete-persistent-volumes-pv/#:~:text=This%20is%20because%20PVs%20are,loss%20or%20other%20unexpected%20behaviors.)) by **Saturn Cloud** for more info.

Comment: @VeeraNagireddy may be I am not able to explain my issue properly.
Here I have defined the “persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy = Delete” in PV.
So when I am deleting the PVC it should automatically delete the data from PV and status of PV would be available. But in my case it is not happening. I am getting error  as mentioned above. How could I solve this?? Is it required to install any CSI plugin for nfs??

Comment: As per [Current reclaim policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#reclaim-policy) : **Delete -- associated storage assets such as AWS EBS or GCE PD volume is deleted**. You can try to install a **CSI plugin** to automatically delete the storage when no longer needed.

Comment: @VeeraNagireddy do you know CSI plugin that is supported with NFS for on premises K8s cluster. Because still I am working on it. It would be great if you have any suggestions. I will update once I will get any solution in mean while.

Comment: @VeeraNagireddy answer.
If nfs volume is configured as static provisioning then it does not support reclaim policy = delete.
But if nfs volume is configured as dynamic provisioning then it supports reclaim policy = delete. So in order to configure nfs as dynamic volume provisioning we need to install CSI pulgins
Kubernetes doesn't include an internal NFS provisioner. You need to use an external provisioner to create a StorageClass for NFS. Here are some examples:
NFS Ganesha server and external provisioner
NFS subdir external provisioner